# Embed exceptional non-compact simply connected simple Lie groups into classical simple Lie groups with preserving centers

Tags: lie-groups, exceptional-groups, noncompact

It is well known that there are exactly 22 exceptional simple real Lie algebras (5 compact, 5 split, 5 complex and 7 others). To each of these algebras there corresponds a unique simply connected (exceptional) Lie group. My question is if there is any literature (textbooks, articles, etc.) concerning the following issue:

Is every non-compact simply connected exceptional Lie group isomorphic to a Lie subgroup $G$ of some classical (not necessarily simply connected) simple Lie group $S$ such that the center of $G$ is contained in the center of S?
If not, is it possible to do so with a semisimple Lie group $S$ whose all simple `factors' are classical?

Comment: How many have you tried? I also want to know what you mean by "classical". Simply connected covers of non-compact Lie groups typically are not algebraic: they do not embed into any matrix group at all. Does "classical" for you mean algebraic? Or simply a group of type ABCD?

Comment: By a classical group I mean any simple Lie group that is not exceptional. And I don't distinguish between linear, algebraic or other - only 'classical' vs. 'exceptional'.

Answer (score 2):

This fails already for the split form of $\mathrm{G}_2$. Every finite-dimensional irreducible representation of its Lie algebra is a constituent of a tensor power of the $7$-dimensional representation.  The corresponding subgroup, which lies in $\mathrm{SO}(4,3)$, has $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ as its maximal compact.  Hence the fundamental group of this image is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and every finite dimensional representation of the simply-connected cover factors through this group.  Hence its simply-connected cover has no finite-dimensional faithful representation.

Comment: Based on their response to my question, I think OP would accept the simply connected cover of SO(4,3) as "classical". To my ear it's a funny usage of "classical", so I could be mistaken about their meaning.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd:  You may be right about that.  I wouldn't have called any group that has no finite-dimensional faithful representation 'classical', but if one's only choices are 'classical' and 'exceptional', then the simply-connected covers of classical matrix groups would be classical.